# "DecorView not attached to window manager" problem in ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity

Tags: android

Recently I received some error from Crashlytics, which seems a IllegalArgumentException was thrown while Activity is destroying:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@8149dd0[] not attached to window manager
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:552)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:433)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:131)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4645)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1757)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I've done some protections while using AsyncTask and ProgressDialog, but this doesn't look like a dismiss() issue.

Nearly 80% was thrown in Android API 8.x

Is there anyone known how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of NightMode, I did know what exactly causes this, but when I use:

```java
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(night ?
    .MODE_NIGHT_YES :
    .MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

to replace the original one:

```java
getDelegate().setLocalNightMode(night ?
    .MODE_NIGHT_YES :
    .MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

and the crashes just gone.

I know this may not be a good answer, but if you come across the same problem someday, this may give you some tip.